# jQuery: How to access an element with a plus sign (+) in the id

Tags: jquery, variables

I have a jQuery loop that appends multiple rows to a table. The number of rows can change at run-time, so the row ID is generated dynamically.

```
$("#tableBody")
    .append($("<tr>")
        .attr('id','row-icon' + currentID)...
```

At a later point, I then need to access these added rows. However, when the value of `currentID` has a '+' symbol in it - I get an "undefined" error when I try to access the row element.

For example, the line below works when `currentID` is "1" - but it fails when the ID is "vm+1".

```
var testID = $("#row-icon" + currentID).attr("id");
```

Am I missing an easy solution to "escape" the extra '+' symbol?

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Locotes/svn8W/3/).

**EDIT:** I should note that the id's are being sent by a 3rd-party - so I have no control over removing the '+' symbol.

Comment: Is it possible to never put the `+` in the ID? Maybe an underscore instead?

Comment: An ID must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits, hyphens , underscores, colons, and periods. So those are illegal id's.

Comment: Read here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3621

Comment: @Tdelang: True in HTML4 but HTML5 is much more permissive about the `id` attribute

Comment: A JavaScript variable should not have a **+** in its name. **+** has a special meaning in JavaScript for concatenation or addition.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD: The *variable* doesn't have a **+** in its name. The  *value* of that variable does have a **+** which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Do it like this I suppose -> http://jsfiddle.net/svn8W/4/

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Read the question again. He gave the id of a row as **vm+1** .

Comment: An HTML5 id can have any character: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: In your `click` function, why not just pass `this` along instead of the actual ID? -> http://jsfiddle.net/svn8W/5/

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD: Read my comment again. There's a difference between a *variable name* and its *value*. We're talking about the *value* of the variable (or the `id` property) in this case. In other words he's not trying to create a variable named `var vm+1`, he's manipulating a variable who's *value* is `vm+1`.

Comment: @adeneo Many thanks, that also works if the ID has multiple '+' symbols. I always thought the '#' symbol had to be used, I haven't seen `[id=` used in that context before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't work, because the `+` sign is a so called meta-characters in jQuery's selector as [explained in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). You should escape it using 2 backslashes:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar"). The W3C CSS
>   specification contains the complete set of rules regarding valid CSS
>   selectors. Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on CSS
>   character escape sequences for identifiers.

So, in your case, you would do (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svn8W/6/)):

```
var test = $("#expand-icon" + currentID.replace(/\+/g, '\\+')).attr("src");
var testID = $("#row-icon" + currentID.replace(/\+/g, '\\+')).attr("id");
```

Comment: Thanks Wouter for adding the demo - that solved it. For anyone with a similar problem, an updated jsfiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Locotes/svn8W/7/

Answer (score 2):

As Others mentioned, using `+` creates an invalid ID.. but in time, I have been challenged to work with some else code with such scenarios..

You could use `\\+` to escape the `+`. See below,

```
var test = $("#expand-icon" + currentID.replace('+', '\\+')).attr("src");
var testID = $("#row-icon" + currentID.replace('+', '\\+')).attr("id");

alert(test+'\n'+testID);
```

**DMEO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZdeC8/

For multiple instances, You can use regEx to replace the string. See below,

```
var test = $("#expand-icon" + currentID.replace(/\+/g, '\\+')).attr("src");
var testID = $("#row-icon" + currentID.replace(/\+/g, '\\+')).attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

In such cases where special symbols are used as part of the ID of an element, they must be escaped in order to let jQuery know that these characters are to be treated literally. for example, if an element has an id "vm+8", the following snippet will get the element:

```
$('#vm\\+8');
```

However, as a rule, try to avoid using special symbols as part of element IDs.